# Magento 2 API - Get list of products with Catalog Price Rule

Tags: magento2, api, product-list, catalog-price-rules

We are using Magento 2.1.7 and building some API endpoints to serve our need.

Following is how we get Products list and send them as json from API call.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Customer\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;

class ProductRepository
{
    protected $_productCollection, $productRepository, $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    )
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    /**
    * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductSearchResultsInterface
    */
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();

        $this->_productCollection = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

We need to know if we can add some search criteria to getProductCollection() method using Filter to get only those products associated to some active catalog price rule with discounted price.

Or if we have any other method to get Products with Catalog Price Rule and discounted Price, guide me in that direction.

Comment: not working for me
my api call is like http://127.0.0.1/Magento/rest/V1/catalogRule/2

Answer (score 3):

When you create a catalog price rule, Magento creates some entries in `catalogrule_product` table. You can see which products are affected by the price rules created.

Unfortunately `ProductRepository` does not allow you to filter by **catalog price rule**. However, you can modify this class by extending it.

The only thing you need to add is the following line.

```
$collection->joinTable('catalogrule_product', 'product_id=entity_id', ['product_id'], null, 'inner');
```

Let's say create `MyProductRepository` as follows:

```
class MyProductRepository extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
{
    public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($collection);

        foreach ($this->metadataService->getList($this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create())->getItems() as $metadata) {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect($metadata->getAttributeCode());
        }
        $collection->joinTable('catalogrule_product','product_id=entity_id', ['product_id'],null, 'inner');
        $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');

        //Add filters from root filter group to the collection
        foreach ($searchCriteria->getFilterGroups() as $group) {
            $this->addFilterGroupToCollection($group, $collection);
        }
        /** @var SortOrder $sortOrder */
        foreach ((array)$searchCriteria->getSortOrders() as $sortOrder) {
            $field = $sortOrder->getField();
            $collection->addOrder(
                $field,
                ($sortOrder->getDirection() == SortOrder::SORT_ASC) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'
            );
        }
        $collection->setCurPage($searchCriteria->getCurrentPage());
        $collection->setPageSize($searchCriteria->getPageSize());
        $collection->load();

        $searchResult = $this->searchResultsFactory->create();
        $searchResult->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
        $searchResult->setItems($collection->getItems());
        $searchResult->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());
        return $searchResult;
    }
}
```

Be careful, you cannot use `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` anymore. You have to call your implementation.

```
$productRepository = $objectManager->get(\MyVendor\MyModule\Model\MyProductRepository::class);
```

Comment: Thank you @bunyamin for detailed answer. I have tried this approach and it gets all products with catalog rule price associated. We also need group by product_id in joinTable() as follows:

`$collection->joinTable('catalogrule_product','product_id=entity_id', ['product_id'],null, 'inner')->getSelect()->group('catalogrule_product.product_id');`

Comment: We also need to select it's discounted price on the basis of catalogrule, how can we select extra fields from joined table?

Comment: @mshakeel I think the **rule applied prices** are stored in `catalogrule_product_price` table. You can also join this table.

Comment: I am returning these products collection from an API call and json returned does not include reduced/special price.

Comment: @mshakeel You need to define your interface and include the rule_price. Do not use `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductSearchResultsInterface`.